# Xamarin Wizard Project Can't Debug

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

So some background information. I am tasked with exploring writing cross platform native applications using Xamarin. Seems pretty basic so far and I'm liking what I'm reading. I have my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise all set up and my remote mac configured on the network. I created a cross platform native app through the project creation wizard in Visual Studio. When I launch a debug session for the iOS app, it does start the target app in the simulator on the remote Mac. However, it never actually thinks it is running fully. It will hang at this output:

```
Launching 'PersonalProject.iOS' on 'iPhone 6 iOS 10.2'...
Loaded assembly: /Users/plm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5A038B6-056F-4E6C-A59C-29ABD8C04CD0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A1B11FF-6C59-4A9B-9CE3-7B8446B1AD48/PersonalProject.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/plm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5A038B6-056F-4E6C-A59C-29ABD8C04CD0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A1B11FF-6C59-4A9B-9CE3-7B8446B1AD48/PersonalProject.iOS.app/System.dll
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /Users/plm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5A038B6-056F-4E6C-A59C-29ABD8C04CD0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A1B11FF-6C59-4A9B-9CE3-7B8446B1AD48/PersonalProject.iOS.app/PersonalProject.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /Users/plm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5A038B6-056F-4E6C-A59C-29ABD8C04CD0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A1B11FF-6C59-4A9B-9CE3-7B8446B1AD48/PersonalProject.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll
```

Eventually, it will fail with something along these lines:

```
The app has been terminated.
Launch failed. The app 'PersonalProject.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 6 iOS 10.2'. Error: An error occurred while executing MTouch. Please check the logs for more details.
```

I've checked the log file in question and it contains nothing more than the same exact phrase.

If I try and put a simple line of Console writing on the action of pressing the button:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            Button.AccessibilityIdentifier = "myButton";
            Button.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                var title = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
                Button.SetTitle (title, UIControlState.Normal);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} clicks!"));
            };
        }
```

the debug session actually errors on this line 17 (UIApplication.Main) in the Main.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace PersonalProject.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

With Unhandled exception error:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Error while resolving expression: One or more errors occurred.
```

If I don't have the console log it will launch the app, but still hanges at those Loaded assembly lines. At this point, I can't hit any breakpoints in my code. I tried adding a breakpoint in the shared code for the button click but it would never hit it, even though the action was being carried out by the simulator.

I'm completely at a loss for how to proceed. I haven't touched anything out of the box of the wizard creation. I was hoping I could at least see the starter project working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this line is missing a parameter: Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} clicks!"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

`Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} clicks!"));`

The `{0}` is a placeholder for a value to output, but you never specify that value, that's why you are getting an error.

Use something like this instead:

`Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} clicks!", count));`

or in C#6 syntax:

`Console.WriteLine($"{count} clicks!");`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, any idea why it didn't show the error on that line instead of the one it showed from the main.cs file?

Comment: No, sorry. Something seems to be screwed with your setup if the app does not start automatically and you cannot debug. Try the usual: restart, reinstall, retry :-)